# MonetDB : Partitioning Data by Time Intervals

Tags: time-series, monetdb

I am using MonetDB for time series data. **I want to partition the tables by time intervals (e.g. by day). Each partition would therefore contain data of a particular day.**  That ideally would later accelerate the query runtime.

From the documentation, I can see that MonetDB provides partitioning as a feature, by I couldn't know how to implement it, I have tried for example: `PARTITION BY DAY`, such is implemented by other systems, by that didn't work.

How could a table be partitioned using a fixed time period interval in MonetDB?

Comment: What kind of partitioning are we talking about here? GROUP BY? partitions in window functions, partitioning tables? In any case there is no syntactical sugar like you are suggesting in MonetDB's SQL implementation. But in each of these cases you can fairly simple express a partition by day in the spirit of the answer below. But I can adjust the answer to fit your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ArisKoning! I am referring to partitioning as a table design to increase query performance. The precision has been added to the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly then. If you think the PARTITION BY DAY is very useful and well used. You could consider changing your github issue into a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

In MonetDB there is no `PARTITION BY DAY`. But what you can do, is

```
CREATE MERGE TABLE merge_table (d DATE) PARTITION BY VALUES USING (d);

CREATE TABLE part_table_30_05_30(d DATE);
CREATE TABLE part_table_30_05_31(d DATE);


ALTER TABLE merge_table ADD TABLE part_table_30_05_30 AS PARTITION IN ('2022-05-30');
ALTER TABLE merge_table ADD TABLE part_table_30_05_31 AS PARTITION IN ('2022-05-31');

INSERT INTO merge_table VALUES ('2022-05-31');

SELECT * FROM merge_table;
+------------+
| d          |
+============+
| 2022-05-31 |
+------------+
1 tuple
SELECT * FROM part_table_30_05_31;
+------------+
| d          |
+============+
| 2022-05-31 |
+------------+
1 tuple
SELECT * FROM part_table_30_05_30;
+---+
| d |
+===+
+---+
0 tuples
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ArisKoning! The partitioning needed here is at the table schema level. I want the data for each day to be stored in a separate partition.

Comment: I see the principle, it's not very convenient for my application and it's not easy to do it on the spot while ingesting new data. I would therefore pass on the partitioning for this time and will create the feature on GitHub like you suggested, thanks @Aris!